# Display with Month name in the Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I would like to display with the text "January" and then the date in the tooltip.

How should I do it? Don't know how to do it.

> https://jsfiddle.net/bfn5u9go/

```js
var data = {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }]
};

window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px;">
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **tooltipTemplate** option:

```
var options = {
    // String - Template string for single tooltips
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= label %> January: <%= value %>"
};

window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Here is sample: https://jsfiddle.net/wckfhrsa/7/

Also, check more tooltip options [global chart configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)